# Why does my div also include a div that is not its child?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Can you please check out this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3047p0wy/
Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid" id="navigation-bar">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="headerspace">
    <a href="http://google.com">
      <span>The title</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-element">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="tabs">
    <li>
      <div class="tab">
        <a href="http://google.com">
          <div class="greysquare">
            <div class='greysquare-content'>
              <div>
                <span>EX</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="notgreysquare"><span>PLORE</span></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

And the css is as follows:

```
.navbar {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

#navigation-bar {
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar-collapse-element {
  height: 100%!important;
}

#tabs {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.tabspace {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.greysquare,
.notgreysquare {
  display: inline;
}

.greysquare {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #CCCCCB;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.greysquare:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.greysquare-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.greysquare-content div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.greysquare-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.notgreysquare {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Basically I have this navbar, and inside it I am trying to work with each navigation tab. The idea is to have the first two letters of a link inside a grey square so that the letter were in the bottom right corner of the square and then the rest of the word was outside of the grey square but on the same line with the first two letters. See the image above to understand what I am looking for (can ignore the colours).
I started with following another fiddle that I found here: https://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/38Tnx/ 
So, as you can see, of the word EXPLORE, the EX is, indeed, placed in the right span, but the greysquare-content, for some reason, at least visually includes the PLORE part of the title which is not even its child, and I cannot figure out why it happens.
I would appreciate any help, really.

Comment: I can't tell where the problem is. All I see is `The title` -- all by itself.

Comment: Check the top right corner? It should be there

Comment: Ok. I can see it. However, I have to make the preview viewport much bigger than I normally have it to see the example.

Comment: Yes, that's probably because of the responsiveness of the navbar. I didn't want to throw out a lot of it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/3047p0wy/3/

The HTML

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="navigation-bar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="headerspace">
            <a href="http://google.com">
              <span>The title</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-element">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="tabs">
            <li>
              <div class="tab">
                <a href="http://google.com">
                  <div style="display: block;">

                    <span class="greysquare-content pull-left">EX</span>
                    <span class="notgreysquare pull-left">PLORE</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

and the CSS

```
.navbar {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

#navigation-bar {
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar-collapse-element {
  height: 100%!important;
}

#tabs {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.tabspace {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
}

.greysquare-content {
  background-color: #CCCCCB;
  padding: 5px;
}

.notgreysquare {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am, however, looking for something different.
I want the word to be together in a word. So, the grey square, which I was asking about, need to stick out to the left and top from the letters. 
And also if you check your solution then you will see that the produced one is 28*30, which is not exactly a square.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the image before. Hows this one? https://jsfiddle.net/3047p0wy/4/

Comment: Cool, that almost looks like I want it! I want the next to be in the bottom of the square, but I hope I can work it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, no, it still doesn't work when I try to increase the padding on greysquare-content, it pushed the text out of the grey box...